# How to assign an id with the combination of letter and variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to assign an id with the combination of letter and variable.
Here is the sample code

```
$("#q1").append("<p id='q' + '"+ questionCount +"'>Question: " + questionCount + "<input type='text'>\
<button type='button' class='buttonMinus' id='"+ questionCount +"'></button></p>");
```

questionCount is a variable.
I can only assign 'q' to each `<p id>` without the value of the questionCount, while I can assign the value of the questionCount to `<button id>`. I have tried several of format, but they still can't work. It really confused me.

Thanks
Ashley

Comment: just as a warning, you do know you are setting the ID to  q + a number
but if that number would happen to be '1' you'll get in trouble with the above script... as you are already appending that to an element with the id  'q1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"<p id='q' + '"+ questionCount +"'>Question: "` should be 
`"<p id='q"+ questionCount +"'>Question: "`.

In your code, you're setting the ID of the element to `q`, and an (unwanted?) attribute which equals the value of `questionCount`.

**Explanation:**
*Let `questionCount` be `9001`, for this example*
When the first part of your code is parsed, the following string operations are executed:

- *create* `<p id='q' + '`
- *add* questionCount
  `<p id='q' + '13'` *(result)*
- *add* `'>Question:`
  `<p id='q' + '13'>` *(result)*

You cannot use + to concatenate attribute values in HTML. Your browser since `+` and `'13'` are invalid HTML attributes, they're ignored. As a result, the final first part is: `<p id='q'>`

Comment: It works! Could you explain the convention or grammar of this? I need to know it because I'm afraid that I will be totally confused next time using this sort of things...

Comment: @nigong: If you think, this is the perfect answer. Please mark as this your answer.

Comment: @nigong I've extended my answer. Do you understand your mistake?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your single quotes are out of whack

```
$("#q1").append("<p id='q" + questionCount +"'>Question: " + questionCount + "<input type='text'>\
<button type='button' class='buttonMinus' id='"+ questionCount +"'></button></p>");
```